# Stacking three bar charts from different series in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am new to matplotlib and cannot figure out how to stack multiple series into one bar chart.

Here is some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
###Data
x_lab =  pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
Series1 = pd.Series([25,35,30])
Series2 = pd.Series([40,35,50])
Series3 = pd.Series([35,30,20])

##Creating the 3 bars to plot##
pl_1 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series1)
pl_2 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series2)
pl_3 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series3)
```

When I run this code the data is superimposed onto each other. I am hoping that the data would be able to be stacked instead.

I have tried this:

```
##First attempt
attempt_1 = plt.bar(x = x_lab, height = [pl_1,pl_2,pl_3], stacked = True)
```

And this:

```
##Second Attempt 
pl_1 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series1, stacked = True)
pl_2 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series2, stacked = True)
pl_3 = plt.bar(x= x_lab,height = Series3, stacked = True)
```

But neither worked. The desired output wold look something like this (colors do not need to match): 
[image]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 3 Series with 3 elements with 3 colors is a bit confusing. The stacks are the first elements of each Series, or a single Series? The green seems to be too small, but they all sum to 100 so unsure.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing.. the first stack would be all of the first elements, the 2nd stack is all the 2nd elements, and the 3rd stack is all of the 3rd elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` + a bar plot with `stacked=True`

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.concat([Series1, Series2, Series3], axis=1)
     .assign(idx=x_lab).set_index('idx')       # just for the labeling
     .plot.bar(stacked=True))
```

[image]

Comment: Just shorter the lines`.plot.bar(stacked=True)
` :-)